# Storing rows of data in an array in a loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

I am running simulations in a financial model. For each simulation I simulate a set of variables and store the results as hard-coded values in my Excel workbook.

I want to speed up my code and have read that writing to the workbook is a slow procedure. I therefore wish to store my result variables of each simulation in an array, and then write the array to the workbook at the end.

I could populate each cell of the row with a new loop, but I believe that would make the code slower. I have been through numerous posts, but have not found any that covers my query.

I want something like this, but I don't know how to write a row of data to an array.

```vb
Dim nSimulations As Integer
Dim nOutput_Variables As Integer
Dim myArray as Variant

'Assign Values
nSimulations = Range("QRA_Simulations").Value 'This will vary, but let's assume 100 simulations
nOutput_Variables = Range("QRA_Output_Copy").Column '25 output values

Redim myArray(nSimulations, nOutput_Variables) 'dimension array to have 100 rows and 25 columns

'Run loop
For iSim = 1 To nSimulations
    'Set simulation variables. 
    Range("QRA_OPEX").Value = Range("QRA_OPEX_Copy").Value
    Range("QRA_CAPEX").Value = Range("QRA_CAPEX_Copy").Value
    
    'Store simulation results as a row in my array
    myArray(iSim,0) = Range("QRA_Output_Copy").Value 'This does not work. The QRA_Output_Copy is a range spanning 1 row and 25 columns, holding 25 values.

Next iSim

Range("Output").Value = myArray 'This just returns #N/A. The output range is 100 rows and 25 colums
```

Comment: Side comment - Since you have made a comment about speed and you are running financial simulations, I would suggest you look at R or Python. From experience, they are far more 'speedy' for the type of work you are trying to do and is easier to scale. I love excel and VBA, but you need to acknowledge it's future limitations especially for what you are trying to achieve. If you are just prototyping, then yeah, VBA is sufficient but be careful when you try and scale to larger data sets.

Comment: I appreciate your point and would prefer the move to R myself. However, I'm not the only one using the financial models and the other financial analysts re not familiar with coding, so I'm stuck with excel.

Comment: It would facilitate help if you described range and minimal sample content of the `QRA_Output_copy` range and which output form you are intending. @JacobKorenBrekke

Comment: Updated in the comment.

Comment: @JacobKorenBrekke Posted an answer to the core question how to integrate row arrays into a whole array information and how to write back the data set. *Feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark if helpful :-)*

Comment: @T.M. Exaclty what I was looking for, thank you! Also appreciate the small code optimizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach via jagged array (Array of arrays)**

I assume you execute simulations as shown in a loop renewing the same output row `QRA_Output_Copy`.

In order to assign the entire row's values at each simulation to the same array, you could use a so called *jagged array* (aka Array of arrays). Consider the array rows as containers holding another array.

There are only three steps to get what you want:

- `[0]`. It suffices to build a variant array of 1 dimension only to hold the number of `nSimulations` as row arrays *(btw I preferred here a 1-based array count)*.
- `[1]`. Assign each row result of `QRA_Output_Copy` to a new simulation row via `myArray(iSim) = Range("QRA_Output_Copy").Value`.
- `[2]`. Furthermore the `Index()` function allows to write results *all at once* via `Application.Index(myArray, 0, 0)` to a given target cell.

**Modified code**

```
Sub JaggedArray()
    Dim t As Double: t = Timer
    'Assign Values
    Dim nSimulations      As Long
    nSimulations = Range("QRA_Simulations").Value ' fixed number of simulations e.g.10000
    
    Dim nOutput_Variables As Long
    ''nOutput_Variables = Range("QRA_Output_Copy").Column       ' //column number??
    nOutput_Variables = Range("QRA_Output_Copy").Columns.Count  ' better: columns.count
    '[0] Build jagged array (as array container)
    Dim myArray           As Variant
    ''ReDim myArray(1 To nSimulations, 1 To nOutput_Variables)  'dimension array to have #rows=simulations and #columns=output variables
    ReDim myArray(1 To nSimulations)                            '<< define "jagged" array
     
    'Run loop
    Dim iSim As Long
    For iSim = 1 To nSimulations
        'run simulation stuff etc.
        '...
        
        '[1] Store simulation results as a row in a 1-dim "jagged" array
        Dim out: out = Range("QRA_Output_Copy").Value
        myArray(iSim) = out                                      '<< assign current row array

    Next iSim
    '[2] Write results all at once
    Range("Output").Resize(UBound(myArray), nOutput_Variables).Value = _
        Application.Index(myArray, 0, 0)
    Debug.Print "Needed " & Format(Timer - t, "0.00 secs")

End Sub
```

**Side note:**

*The above code writes the whole array to a target. If you want, howver to get a single item out of `myArray` you have to reference it as follows:*

```
    myArray(n)(i,j)
```

*where `n` is the simulation counter, `i` and `j` the array indices. As I passed each single row as a datafield array (1-based 2-dim array by default), the single 'row' index `i` always equals 1 and `j` refers to a 'column' number in each passed set of row items.*